# How do I include a subdirectory and its content to the Sphinx output/build directory?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have the following directory structure for my Sphinx project.

- root

  - build
  - source

    - index.md
    - snippets

I want to copy `root/source/snippets` to `build/html/snippets` as is; this directory has code snippet files.

I don't think `.. include::`, `:download:` and `html_extra_path` are what I need. Is there a way to do this using the build configuration? Or is the only way to modify the `make` build scripts.

I am using Python v2.7.13 and Sphinx v1.5.1.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this question, and can answer for Sphinx 3.3 with Python 3.8.

All I had to do was put `html_extra_path = ['extra']` into `conf.py`. Then I made `docs/extra/snippets`. Now `snippets` and all of its content are copied into `_build/html/snippets`.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the makefile is trivial.  I took mine, added just two lines, and it worked for me.

```
html:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/html $(BUILDDIR)/doctrees
    $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/html/snippets
    cp snippets/* $(BUILDDIR)/html/snippets
```

Otherwise, I haven't tried this, but maybe [sphinxcontrib-rawfiles](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-rawfiles/0.1.1) will copy files into the directory you want.